# spring kafka : different json payload on the same topic

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I need to send different JSON payload on the same Kafka Topic (for example, Foo, Bar, Car ...) without using parent class

Based on spring kafka documentation, I can use `@KafkaListener` at the class-level and specify `@KafkaHandler` at the method level ( [doc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/src/reference/asciidoc/kafka.adoc) )

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic")
static class MultiListenerBean {

    @KafkaHandler
    public void listen(Foo foo) {
        ...
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    public void listen(Bar bar) {
        ...
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    public void listen(Car car) {
        ...
    }
}
```

but I get this exception:

```
[org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.listener.LoggingErrorHandler - Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = myTopic, partition = 1, offset = 0, CreateTime = 1508859519287, checksum = 3297149058, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 13, key = null, value = {"foo":"foo"})
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: No method found for class java.util.LinkedHashMap
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.getHandlerForPayload(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:92)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.getMethodNameFor(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:147)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.getMethodAsString(HandlerAdapter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:188)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:794)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:738)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:570)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have also tried this approach but it's not working:

```
   @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic")
   public void receive(ConsumerRecord<String, ?> payload)
   {
      if (payload.value() instanceof Foo)
      {
         //
      }
      else if (payload.value() instanceof Car)
      {
         //
      }
   }
```

How I can configure my producer and consumer to send different JSON Payload on the same Topic using spring kafka?

Comment: Show, please, how do you deserialize from JSON.

Answer (score 2):

There is a catch-22 when using JSON and multi-method listeners; we need to know the type to route to the right method; we can't infer the type for conversion from the method signature because we don't know which method we want to call yet.

You need a message converter that can figure out the type, either from the data, or using a `Header` (with Kafka 11).

Then, after the converter has converted to the proper type, we can then figure out which method to call.

With your second attempt, the `ConsumerRecord` will contain the raw JSON; you will need to use an `ObjectMapper` to do the conversion but, again, you'll need some hint as to what type you want to convert to (or do it with brute force, until success).