# How to get multiple objects from one Kafka message using Header

Tags: apache-kafka, header, listener, spring-kafka

I want to deserialize different objects from one message (from the same topic), and according to object type save/update it to the appropriate table in DB. As Gary mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915365/spring-kafka-different-json-payload-on-the-same-topic) I can use headers to provide information to which type my object must be deserialized. Can you help with examples of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See sample-02 [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/master/samples).

> **Sample 2**

> This sample demonstrates a simple producer and a multi-method consumer; the producer sends objects of types `Foo1` and `Bar1` and the consumer receives objects of type `Foo2` and `Bar2` (the objects have the same field, `foo`).

> The producer uses a `JsonSerializer`; the consumer uses a `ByteArrayDeserializer`, together with a `ByteArrayJsonMessageConverter`  which converts to the required type of the listener method argument.
> We can't infer the type in this case (because the type is used to choose the method to call).
> We therefore configure type mapping on the producer and consumer side.
> See the `application.yml` for the producer side and the `converter` bean on the consumer side.

> The `MultiMethods` `@KafkaListener` has 3 methods; one for each of the known objects and a fallback default method for others.

> Run the application and use curl to send some data:

> `$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/send/foo/bar`

> `$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/send/bar/baz`

> `$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/send/unknown/xxx`

> **Console:**

> `Received: Foo2 [foo=bar]`

> `Received: Bar2 [bar=baz]`

> `Received unknown: xxx`

Comment: Hi, Gary! Thanks a lot, exactly what I was searching for. One more question, I suppose there is must be StringDeserializer for consumer value-deserializer as you said because now it's ByteArrayDeserializer in application.yml, thx again!

Comment: Yes. I changed it yesterday. Using byte arrays is more efficient, it avoids an unnecessary bytes to String conversion. The ByteArrayJsonMessageConverter didn’t exist when I first wrote the sample. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/b399f2996ead0b3c23b785bebdcf3cb7ec4664ae