# Listen to multiple type of objects in the same Kafka topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a use case where I would be receiving two kinds of object in the same topic. The issue I am facing is that all the objects are going to the same listener. The second listener is not being used.

My listeners are similar to below

```
@EnableKafka
@Service
public class consumerService {

  @KafkaListener(topic = "t", groupId = "g" containerFactory = "fooContainerFactory")
  public void consume1(Foo foo) {
     logger.info("I got : " + foo);
  }

  @KafkaListener(topic = "t", groupId = "g" containerFactory = "barContainerFactory")
  public void consume2(Bar bar) {
     logger.info("I got : " + bar);
  }

}
```

The container factory for Foo is below, I have a similar one for Bar.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConsumerConfig {


  @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
  private String bootstrapAddress;

  @Value(value = "${group.id}")
  private String groupId;

  public Map<String, Object> clickConsumerFactory() {
    /** Set the consumer properties here */
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
    return props;
  }

  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Foo> clickKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    /** Listener factory for the class 'Foo' */
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Foo> factory
            = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(clickConsumerFactory()));
    factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
    factory.setErrorHandler(((exception, data) -> LOGGER.info("There was an error " + exception)));
    return factory;
  }
}
```

I tried using KafkaHandler but I don't know how to specify the individual container factory(for Foo : FooContainerFactory, for Bar: BarContainerFactory)
I am stuck at this for a few hours. Can somebody tell me what should I change?

Comment: If you topic has single partition, one of your consumer will be idle. Because they are belong to same  consumer group (same groupId).

Answer (score 0):

I could be way off here. As i am not sure how @KafkaListener works. But, off the top of my head, there are chances that there is only 1 partition and the first kakfaListener is assigned to that. so, any new listeners (similar to kafka consumers) will not get assigned any partition as there is just 1 partition to begin with. So, the new Listeners will sit idle waiting for some partition to get assigned so that they can start reading the data.

You can verify this by disabling the first KafkaListener and then running your application. The second listener would automatically kick in.

or, if your topic already has multiple partitions then, it could be happening because of the key of the message as keys can be used to send data to one partition. and your first listener is assigned to that partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. If the same topic contains both Foo and Bar objects; there is no way for the framework to filter out the records that don't match.

And, as has been said in other comments, answers, since they are both in the same group, they will each get a subset of records.

The simplest solution is to use two different topics.

If that's not possible, you have to use a class level listener with `@KafkaHandler` methods, but then you need to do the conversion in the deserializer instead of the framework figuring out the type from the method parameter.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66496761/how-to-get-multiple-objects-from-one-kafka-message-using-header/66497050#66497050) for a link to a sample that shows how to do that.

Comment: If I need to process different types of events (with different Avro schemas) on the same topic (because I need to process them in the same order as published), then class-level listener with @KafkaHandler is the only way to go?

Comment: That, or consume `Object` and perform the casts yourself.